# Reading data from a SPI register and storing into array

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, spi

I'm trying to write code for a SPI slave device that reads data from the MISO line.

Here is the register map for the SPI device.

[image]

Basically my code looks at the `status` register and checks two conditions.

1. Is the `RRDY` bit set? (which indicates that there is data in the RX register)
2. Is the `ROE` bit not set? (which indicates that recieve over-run error has not occured)

If these conditions are met then I put the recieved char into the array `buf`.

I am sending the device the characters 'A', 'B' and 'C'.

When I recieved 'C' I break the loop and then print out the contents of `buf'.

My question is, `buf` only contains 'C', '0', '0'.

Is there something wrong with my logic?

```
char ibuf[32];
int chr;
int ptr;

while(1) { //keep checking

  //if RRDY set and ROE is not 1
   if (((*spi_status_reg >> 7) & 1) && (!(*spi_status_reg >> 3) & 1)) {

    //macro to read char from the rx register 
    chr = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_SPI_RXDATA(SPI_1_SLAVE_BASE); 
    ibuf[ptr] = chr; // store it
    ptr ++;

    //if 'C' then exit
    if(chr == 'C') {
      printf("Got C\r\n");
      break;
    }
  }
}

printf("Exit\r\n");

for (int i= 0; i<3; i++) {
  printf("Buffer %x\r\n", ibuf[i]);
}
```

Comment: You fill `buf` but then print `ibuf`

Comment: Also, is ptr set to `0` before the while?

Comment: @Toby Yes - `ptr` is 0, buf was a posting mistake, fixed now and updated the if statement to be more readable. Thanks

Comment: You should step through the code with a debugger and check the values in the variables are as expected, use of a debugger is a basic skill requirement for programming.

Comment: Also you might want to make explicit the brackets on the second condition:  `(!((*spi_status_reg >> 3) & 1))`

Comment: @Toby I'm a little confused does `(!((*spi_status_reg >> 3) & 1))` check that the `ROE` bit is not set?

Comment: Exactly. This is not the same as what you currently have as the `!` operator should apply to the Boolean result of the `&` operation instead of applying only to the integer result of the `>>` operation (BTW, this shows the difference between `!` and `~`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056180/c-not-operator-applied-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the Boolean not operator (`!`) incorrectly in the second condition in your `if`.

Instead of doing `!BooleanValue` you are doing `!IntegerValue` which will be `True` any time that `(*spi_status_reg  >> 3)` is any non-zero value.

Try `!((*spi_status_reg  >> 3) & 1)` instead.

(Or possibly `~(*spi_status_reg  >> 3) & 1`, but this is less readable)

See [C not operator applied to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056180/c-not-operator-applied-to-int) and http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. The latter shows that `!` has a greater *precedence* than `&`, this is why the explicit brackets are required.

FYI: Shifting the `1` is better than shifting the register value because then the compiler can optimize the value, (probably saving it as a constant; e.g. for `(*spi_status_reg & (1 << 7))` the compiler will probably replace `(1 << 7)` with the constant `128` at compile time)